# Javascript Json Unique Value Sort and Store

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to sort json unique value. Here is an example:

```
let arif =  [{
        "name": "Arif",
        "label": "arif"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hasan",
        "label": "arif"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tomal",
        "label": "tomal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Biswas",
        "label": "tomal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Maruf",
        "label": "maruf"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rahman",
        "label": "maruf"
    },
    {
        "name": "Iqbal",
        "label": "maruf"
    }
  ];

console.log(arif);

let myvalue;
if (arif) {
  myvalue = _.uniq(arif, function (arif) {
    return arif.label;
  });
}

console.log(myvalue);
```

In the above code I used [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/) to get the unique value of json variable `label`. I want to store the each value of `label` in another value like this:

```
 let newvalue1 = myvalue[0].label;
```

I know I can get the length of `myvalue`, but how can I store the value dynamically instead of using `myvalue[0]`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: [There is no JSON in your question, only JavaScript](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: My expected output is " let newvalue1=myvalue[0].label , let newvalue2=myvalue[1].label, let newvalue3=myvalue[2].label" till "myvalue.length"

Answer (score 2):

Two things are here.

1. First find uniq value

   `let uniqArr = _.uniq(arif, function (item) { return item.label; });`
2. Then sort the uniq values arr **uniqArr**

   `let sortArr = _.sortBy( uniqArr, function( item ) { return item.label; } );`

so in `sortArr` you will get

`let newvalue2=sortArr[1].label`

`let newvalue3=sortArr[2].label`

or you can loop with `_.each`